# JavaScript/jQuery - Multiple Wack-a-Mole Qs: (Increment Score, x/y positioning, click event listener - corrected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, increment, addeventlistener

I'm a beginner, obviously, and working on a project for class. I managed to solve 1 step through the site & 1 on my own, but the last 4 are getting more confusing the more I search through these other questions, which I've been doing all day and most of yesterday. I've gone through W3Schools,  TutorialsPoint, and tizag.com and still can't figure it out.

Here are the instructions:

- Write two functions that generate random whole numbers. One function should return numbers between 0 and 300 (for the y positioning) and the other should return numbers between 0 and 600 (x positioning). Call them (temporarily) from the jQuery ready function and alert() the values.
- In the jQuery ready function, write some Javascript/jQuery code which adds a jQuery click event listener to button#start_button. For the time being, add an alert() to test that the button click is working.
- Create a function (outside the jQuery ready function) which increments the user's score  when called and updates the HTML in span#score. Hint: You should create a global variable to keep track of the score.
- Call your score increment function within Document Ready  for testing purposes.

This is what I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm very frustrated.

```
var mole='<img src="img/mole.jpg"/>'
    var score=docutment.getElementById("#score");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#gamespace").show().html(mole);
        $("#timer").show()
        document.getElementById("start_button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
            function myFunction(){
                alert(Okay);
            }; //end alert
    }); //end.ready
    function getRndInteger(min, max){
        var y=Math.floor((Math.random()*300)+1);
            function click(){
                alert(y);
            }; //end alert y
    }; //end y
    function getRndInteger(min, max){
        var x=Math.floor((Math.random()*600)+1);
            function click(){
                alert(x);
            }; //end alert x 
    }; //end x
    function displayScore(){
        score.innerHTML=
    }; //end score
```

I guess I should add the rest of the code if anyone whats to test it out.

```
<div id="content">

    <h1>Whack-A-Mole</h1>

    <p>After clicking "start", you will have 30 seconds to click
    as many moles as you can. The moles appear randomly so be ready! </p>

    <div id="controls">
        <span id="score">0 pts</span>
        <button type="button" id="start_button">Start!</button>
    </div>

    <div id="timer">30 seconds left</div>

    <div id="gamespace">



    </div>

</div>
```

Fixed it!

```
<script>
    var mole='<img src="img/mole.jpg"/>';
    var score=0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#gamespace").html(mole);
        $("#score").click(increment);
        $("#timer").show();
        $("#start_button").click(function(){
            alert("Okay");
            }); //end alert
        alert(getRndNum());
        alert(getRndNumY());
    }); //end.ready
    function getRndNum(min, max){
        var x=Math.floor((Math.random()*600)+1);
            return x;
    }; //end x
    function getRndNumY(min, max){
        var y=Math.floor((Math.random()*300)+1);
            return y;
    }; //end y 
    function increment(){
        $("#score")[0].innerHTML=score;
    }; //end increment
</script>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any attempt to answer your question because it's too broad for this platform which expects a specific question that will give a specific answer. What you have done is asked for at least four expectations from some code you wrote and want help with that. That's not what SO is for or how it works. If not for this being a weekend evening, this would have easily been closed by now.

Comment: Sorry! I thought I was doing it right by making a serious effort to finish the whole thing before asking any questions. I didn't realize I would be too stupid to get any more of it right on my own. I did not know I should have asked each question as I went along. It would have made things easier! Thank you for explaining the guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some comments on your code:

Don't forget to end all your lines with semi-colons

```
var mole='<img src="img/mole.jpg"/>'
```

Make sure your spelling is correct ('document' is misspelled).

```
var score=docutment.getElementById("#score");
```

You're also mixing jQuery and vanilla JavaScript here. To get the element using vanilla JavaScript, you would write the following (note the lack of a # symbol):

```
var score = document.getElementById('score');
```

Whereas using jQuery you would write:

```
var score = $('#score');
```

'#gamespace' and '#timer' are already visible, so no need to call .show() on them.

```
$("#gamespace").show().html(mole);
$("#timer").show()
```

Again, you can use jQuery here:

```
// JavaScript
document.getElementById("start_button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

// jQuery
$('#start_button').click(myFunction);
```

This will look for a variable named Okay. If you want to show the text 'okay', you need to wrap it in quotes.

```
function myFunction(){
    alert(Okay);
}; //end alert
```

Here, you're defining two functions with the same name, so your second one is overwriting your first.

```
function getRndInteger(min, max){
    // do stuff...
}; //end y
function getRndInteger(min, max){
    // do stuff...
}; //end x
```

You're also not returning any value from the function. You're defining a function called 'click', but you're never calling it or binding it to anything. You're also taking in two parameters (min and max) which you don't use.

```
function getRndInteger(min, max){
    var y=Math.floor((Math.random()*300)+1);
        function click(){
            alert(y);
        }; //end alert y
}; //end y
```

To write a function that just returns a value from 0 to 300, you would do this:

```
function randomX(){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*300);
    return x;
}
```

You could alert an outcome of randomX by writing

```
alert(randomX());
```

I hope that helps you with cleaning up the code you already have, the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) is very helpful and will give you an idea of what parameters you need to pass into certain functions, what they do, and what they'll return.

Comment: Thank you. The mole and timer didn't show until I added them, those were the first 2 steps that I got right. Something I just did made them go away, though. I tried taking out the ,show() and keeping it in, no difference. They're gone now! I made the other changes but still nothing happens. Also, I don't have any idea what to put in the final function at the bottom.

Here is the new code...if I can figure out where to put it.

Comment: The last function (displayScore) is breaking your code because it contains an unfinished expression. If you delete that things should show up as expected.

Comment: The getRndIntegerX/Y functions are still not being called at any point, which is why no alerts are appearing. You can call them from within the document ready function. Also, once a function returns a value, it stops running. So if you call them as they are, they will return the value of x/y, but no alert will be displayed.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I tried deleting that but I must not have gotten all of it. They are back. The problem with calling the x/y functions is that I'm not sure where to call them. Pretty pathetic, I know!

Comment: The instructions you posted say this: "Call them (temporarily) from the jQuery ready function and alert() the values.", so you can do that by adding `alert(getRndIntegerX());` somewhere in your document.ready function (and removing the alerts from the getRndIntegerX/Y functions themselves)